# Trying to scrape url link and name with scrapy. python

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the list of company names put in an anchor tag and also the link mentioned in the anchor tag from [here](https://www.adapt.io/directory/industry/telecommunications/A-1)

```
<a content="https://www.adapt.io/company/a-a-technology-group" 
href="https://www.adapt.io/company/a-a-technology-group">A&amp;A Technology 
Group</a>
```

eg: company_name = A&A technology group ,

source_url = https://www.adapt.io/company/a-a-technology-group

could someone tell me the way to extract the url and also the company name

```
import scrapy

class CompanySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'company'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.adapt.io/directory/industry/telecommunications/A-1'
    ]

    def parse(self,response):
        all_div_company = response.css('div.DirectoryList_linkItemWrapper__3F2UE ')
        company_name = all_div_company.xpath('a/text').extract()
        source_url = all_div_company.xpath('a/@href').extract()

        yield{
            'company_name' : company_name,
            'source_url' : source_url
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to scrape all of the companies one by one.

```
import scrapy

class CompanySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'company'
    start_urls = ['https://www.adapt.io/directory/industry/telecommunications/A-1']
    custom_settings = {"TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED" : False,"ROBOTSTXT_OBEY" : False}
    
    def parse(self,response):
        for company in response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'DirectoryList_link')]"):
            yield{
                'company_name' : company.xpath("./a/text()").get(),
                'source_url' : company.xpath("./a/@href").get()
            }
```

I wrote the script for you. You have to scrape in for loop and the website doesn't allow scraper so you have to set  `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = FALSE` in the settings.

Comment: thanks, it worked. could u explain what TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED does

Comment: It's like my default settings you don't have to use it. I am not using the telnet console because  I am scraping about 2000 pages in a row and at every spider, Scrapy opens the telnet and each takes a couple of seconds cause of that I am always closing for saving time that's it.

Comment: You are welcome please don't forget to accept the answer.